# Why are fonts not rendering in GIMP?

Tags: updates, kubuntu, display, fonts, text

After updates, some text is not rendering.  I think it is in the form of binary.

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEBMP.png) of the issue in GIMP.

[image]

Comment: Is it only like this in GIMP? the "binary" characters are just plaintext but the font can't display them, looks like a missing font issue.

Comment: not only in GIMP but all the applications and terminal

Comment: not at all it does not answer i have changed font but nothing happened